# Set Azure DNs setting from CSV file for Network interface cards

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting, dns

I'm trying to set DNS settings for networkinterface cards on Azure. I have a CSV file which has server name, NIC, dnsip1, dnsip2

I thought it would be something like this.

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\test.csv -Header rgName,NIC,DNSIP1,DNSIP2 | Foreach-Object { 
$n = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $_.nic -ResourceGroupName $_.rgname $n.DnsSettings.DnsServers = '$_.DNSIP1','$_.DNSIP2' 
}
```

Can I use the $n variable and keep reassigning it within a loop, I've tried this and I keep getting prompted for

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

Comment: Hi, does the answer work for you?

Comment: `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface` only could get NIC information. If you want to modify it, you should use `Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworkinterface?view=azurermps-5.0.0) to set DNS setting. The following script should work for you.

```
$csv="d:\nic.csv"
$NICS=Import-Csv $csv
ForEach ($kvp in $NICS){
    $nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $kvp.rgName -Name $kvp.NIC
    $nic.DnsSettings.DnsServers.Add($kvp.DNSIP1)
    $nic.DnsSettings.DnsServers.Add($kvp.DNSIP2)
    $nic | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface
}
```